# Iterate over a Map<String, MyObj[]> twice, one for keys and one for the array

Tags: angular

I have a map of `Map<String,MyObj[]>` e.g. `{{str1, [obj_1, obj_2]}, {str2,[obj_3, obj_4]}}` and would like to display the contents as follow in a table:

```
str_1
obj_1.field1>
obj_2.field1>
str_2
obj_3.field1>
obj_4.field1>
```

In other words, I will need to iterate over the Map (for the keys) and in each iteration I need to iterate over the MyObj[] array. How can I achieve this with e.g. `ngFor`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use nested loops. You can use the `keyvalue` pipe to get the `mapelement` with `key` and `value`, where the value of each element is the array. You can then iterate over `mapelement.value` to get all values of the array

```html
<div *ngFor="let mapelement of themap | keyvalue">
  <div>{{mapelement.key}}</div>
   <div *ngFor="let arrayelement of mapelement.value">
    {{arrayelement.field1}}
   </div>
</div>
```